# Updating my training model on the fly

Tags: mahout, bayesian

I am using the Naive bayes classifier of apache mahout. Say I train a model with 100 training data, and I have got 50 more training data. Is there any way I can append the new data into the trained model, or should I re-train with 150 data from scratch?

If this feature is not currently available, is it in the cards for future releases?

Comment: Hello, did you ever get around this issue?

Comment: Did you do it through database or are you doing it through flat files like 20 news example?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I use flat files!